# Natural isomorphism of morphisms into an object of a category imply isomorphism of objects.

Tags: category-theory

*From [Leinster - Basic Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09375) - Q4.1.27 p93*

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a locally small category, and $A$ in $\mathcal{A}$. Define $H_A = \mathcal{A}(\mathit{-},A)\colon \mathcal{A}^{\mathit{op}} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ as follows.

For objects $B$ in $\mathcal{A}$ , put $H_A(B) = \mathcal{A}(B, A)$;
for maps $g\colon B^\prime \rightarrow B$, $B^\prime$ in $\mathcal{A}$,  define
$H_A(g) = \mathcal{A}(g, A) = \mathit{−} ◦ g : \mathcal{A}(B, A) \rightarrow \mathcal{A}(B^\prime, A)$

Let $A, A^\prime \in \mathcal{A}$ with $H_A \cong H_A^\prime$ .
Prove directly that $A \cong A^\prime$.

Below is my attempt. I feel I am missing something, any pointers or comments to improve are welcome.

*** My attempted answer ***

We are given $H_A$ is naturally isomorphic if and only if $\alpha_A: H_A(B) \rightarrow H_{A^\prime}(B)$ is isomorphic for all $B$ in $\mathcal{A}$.

The naturality square of $H_A$ is constructed below.
For every map $g: B^\prime \rightarrow B$, $B, B^\prime$ in $\mathcal{A}$, the following square commutes

[image]

Moreover, since $H_A \cong H_{A^\prime}$,  $\alpha_A$ is an isomorphism for every $B$ in $\mathcal{A}$.

Now consider the square below. For an arbitrary $B$ in $\mathcal{A}$ we need to show there is a bijection between the component $\alpha_A$ and a morphism $\overline{f}$ in $\mathcal{A}$.

[image]

But $(\mathit{-})^B$ and $(\mathit{-})(B)$ are unique and inverses so take $f,\overline{f}\colon A \rightarrow A^\prime$ as $\overline{f}(A) = f(A^B)(B) = A^\prime$ and  we have our required bijection, hence $A$ and $A^\prime$ are isomorphic. Note that the isomorphism of $\alpha_A$ must hold for all $B$ in $\mathcal{A}$, for $\overline{f}$ to be an isomorphism in $\mathcal{A}$. To see why, suppose there exists a $B$, such that $\alpha_A$ is a bijective morphism but not an isomorphism, then $\overline{f}$ is not an isomorphism, and we have a contradiction. Suppose, alternatively, there exists a $B$, such that $\alpha_A$ is not bijective, then our expression for $\overline{f}$ implies $\overline{f}$ is not bijective, and again we have a contradiction.

Comment: You should not need to use proof by contradiction in basic category theory. It usually means your proof is more convoluted than it needs to be. For this particular claim there is a short easy direct proof. Here is a hint: consider $\textrm{id}_A \in H_A (A)$ and $\textrm{id}_{A'} \in H_{A'} (A')$.

Comment: @Zhen Lin, $id_A \in H_A(A)$ can be considered as $1_A$ in $\mathcal{A}$, is that correct?

Comment: That’s just a matter of notation.